# Using Copernicus Global Land Cover Layers: CGLS-LC100 collection 3 in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, copernicus

I have some excperience of using GEE, but I would like to get to know the dataset named Copernicus Global Land Cover Layers: CGLS-LC100 collection 3. I would like to get more familiar about its possibilities and examples.

Is it possible to find any tutorials or training materials to follow based on this dataset or maybe someone has done something using this dataset to show more possibilities of using it? I am familiar with GEE developers page example, but it doesn't say much.

For example, what do I get, when I don't select 'discrete_classification' band? Is it possible to calculate the land cover change during the monitoring period? How? Is it possible to add a legend to the map for better visualisation?

```
var dataset = ee.Image("COPERNICUS/Landcover/100m/Proba-V-C3/Global/2019")
.select('discrete_classification');

Map.setCenter(-88.6, 26.4, 1);

Map.addLayer(dataset, {}, "Land Cover");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very specific, but you can learn more about the dataset in the Dataset Catalog.  For instance the available bands are described here:
https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_Landcover_100m_Proba-V-C3_Global#bands